# count the occurrence of letters in a string and output the letter with the highest occurrence

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to count the occurence of each letter in a string and afterwards find out the letter with the highes occurrence and then return it as a char to the main method. Im just a beginner in coding so I would appreciate simple answers and solutions without adding anything from the library. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it

What I have right now:

to count the occurrence for each letter (doesnt work):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) 
{
    if (s[0] == s[i])
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

to find out the highest number in the array:

```
int max = s[0];
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] > max)
    {
        max = s[i];
     }
}
```

afterwards i want to return the value as a char and output the letter

Comment: `var result = s.GroupBy(c => c).MaxBy(g => g.Count()).Key;`

Comment: what does "doesnt work" mean? Any exception? Unexpected results? What is your input-data and the expected outcome?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain if i try to display the count for each letter it shows me the same value for every letter

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i want a solution which doesnt include using the system library and i need Linq for that solution

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the existing code is there is only one `count` variable, but there are many different letters in the string. You need a way to keep a separate count for each different letter you encounter. A `Dictionary<char,int>` might be a good start, or an `int[]` with 26 items (one for each letter in order) could do the job. There are other structures that can work, too.

Beyond that, this looks like a learning problem, where you would not be well-served by seeing more code, but rather will do better to puzzle out the rest on your own.

Comment: So im guessing there isnt any way to not use the system library as a solution.

Comment: You always need `System`, but you can certainly do this without `Linq` or fancy collections. There is code here that only uses Linq to populate an initial empty array: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RlDcHy

Answer (score 0):

You can query string with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

var result = s
  .GroupBy(c => c)
  .MaxBy(g => g.Count())
  .Key;
```

No Linq solution can use `Dictionary<char, int>` where `Key` is character and `Value` is its frequency.

```
var freq = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (char c in s)
  if (freq.TryGetValue(c, out int count))
    freq[c] = count + 1;
  else
    freq.Add(c, 1);

int maxCount = 0;
char result = '\0';

foreach (var pair in freq)
  if (pair.Value > maxCount) {
    maxCount = pair.Value;
    result = pair.Key; 
  }
```